# Allowed Memory Size Error in WordPress

Tags: errors, memory

My WordPress is always down. I contacted my host and they said that the server is fine. My WordPress site has some basic plugins which are

1. all in one seo
2. seo search tagging
3. google xml
4. robots.txt
5. related post

I can't find what is my problem. I have some HTML files which are working fine, but my Wordpress site is not working. I think the issue is with Wordpress. Do I need to reinstall Wordpress to fix the issue? Thanks.

I have this error in error_log. I think it is a memory problem.

> `[28-Apr-2011 13:32:20] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 82 bytes`

Comment: Define Down....

Comment: Unless you can identify a particular programming error that is responsible, then site downtime is off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ok i found error in error_log... please help me... thank you...

Answer (score 4):

The amount of memory that is allocated to PHP is insufficient.

Add this to your wp-config.php file:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');
```

If that doesn't work, the chances are your host has this locked down and you can't change it, in which case you either need to simplify your site, or move hosts.

Answer (score 3):

Many *Related Posts*-type Plugins are notoriously resource-hogging, due to ineffecient (or frequent) SQL querying.

Of your installed Plugins, I would first investigate your "Related Post" Plugin.